# How to Export proportional UV Layout in blender?

Tags: uv

Because I want to use on the mold.But the blender uv size is always fixed at 36.12cm * 36.12cm.

Comment: Can you give more context?, not sure what you asking here.

Comment: Why not convert the pixel size to cm before exporting?

Comment: How to do? I do not know.

Comment: If you need proper export for mold you should use program as pepakura designer works fine . I tried older scrypt for blender but didnt work for me

Comment: why do you need to convert to physical metrics the 3d object is going to be scaled anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I am understanding your question exactly as default Blender UV export size is `1024 x 1024` or about `27cm` on the *x* and *y*.

When exporting UVs from Blender, after going to *UVs* > *Export UV Layout* there is a little panel in the bottom left where you can modify the output size.

[image]

The exporter only takes values in pixels, if you want definite values you can just simply use a converter like this one. [translatorscafe.com](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/typography/calculator/pixel-%28X%29-to-centimeter-%5Bcm%5D/), just put your desired centimeter value in and it will give you the equivalent in pixels.

As per brecht's comment below, conversion among such units is not as simple as it seems, one key factor involved is the [dots per inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) (DPI) of your current display. To take that into account, you can use [this converter](http://easycalculation.com/pixtomm.php).

Comment: :), I mean is to export the model size 1:1 UV map.However, the export UV layout panel can not be set metric units, only set the pixel size ：（.

Comment: Converting between pixels and centimeters is not as simple an operation is this website makes it seem, it depends on the screen or printer DPI or pixels/inch. This website does not even specify which DPI it assumes so it might not match the default DPI in whatever other program you are using.

Comment: @brecht added a better one that takes DPI into account. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying, I love blender.